# Gaussian elimination choice for matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

This questions isn't completely about mathematics, it is also part of computer science. I hope here is the correct place for it.

I studied about the gaussian elimination algorithm (I want to implement it in Octave). The system of linear equations is Ax=b. At each step p, I multiply A to the left with a matrix $T_p = I_n - t_p * e_p^T$ where $e_p$ is the p-th column from the n*n identity matrix and the T denotes its transpose. Also, $t_p$ is a row vector with first $p$ entries equal to 0 and $t_p(i)= a(i,p)/a(p,p)$ for i >= p+1.
My question is: why was the matrix $T_p$ chosen this way? To be more precise, what is the $t_p*e_p^T$? Why not write $T_p = I_n - B$ for example, with B arbitrary matrix? As far as I calculated, $t_p*e_p^T*A$ is a matrix which has on every row the elements of the p-th row from A, but multiplied to an element from t. They are of the form: $t_p(i)*a(p,j)$ on the i-th row and j-th column of the matrix.

Comment: I would not think of that description first for the Gaussian elimination algorithm. Try to understand it in terms of row operations to begin with. The point of the matrix $T_p$ is that multiplying it has the effect of performing those row operations. Once you break it down that way, you can see if you need answers to "Why do we perform these row operations in Gaussian elimination?" and/or "Why does left multiplication by $T_p$ have the same effect as performing these row operations?"